# VB.net Check if Array Element Exists

Tags: arrays, vb.net, element

I have 2 sub routines that call another to write a log file. The data is put in an array called LogData(). Sub routine 1 contains 3 elements, while sub routine 2 contains 4. If I just write the log using all LogData() elements, it errors when sub routine 1 runs, because it doesn't contain any element at LogData(3). How can I check if LogData element (3) holds a value, and if so, write it to the log? I tried using the below If statement, but this errors:

```
If (Not LogData(3) Is Nothing) Then
w.WriteLine("Address   : {0}", LogData(3))
End If
```

I also tried:

```
If LogData.Count > 2 Then
If Not arrayList(yourIndex) Is Nothing Then
```

If I were just writing LogData() to the log file, i could just use a loop. However because i'm adding text between each element I can't do that.

Sub 1:

```
        Dim appData As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
        Dim LogPath As String = appData & "\myApplication"
        Dim LogData() As String = {Username, Action, Domain}
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(LogPath)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(LogPath)
        End If
        Using w As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(LogPath & "\log.txt")
            Log(LogData, w)
        End Using
```

Sub 2:

```
        Dim appData As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
        Dim LogPath As String = appData & "\myApplication"
        Dim LogData() As String = {Username, Action, Domain, Address}
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(LogPath)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(LogPath)
        End If
        Using w As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(LogPath & "\log.txt")
            Log(LogData, w)
        End Using
```

Log sub:

```
Public Shared Sub Log2(LogData As Array, w As TextWriter)
    w.Write(vbCrLf)
    w.WriteLine("Log Entry          : {0} - {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
    w.WriteLine("username : {0}", LogData(0))
    w.WriteLine("Action   : {0}", LogData(1))
    w.WriteLine("Domain   : {0}", LogData(2))
    If (Not LogData(3) Is Nothing) Then
        w.WriteLine("Address   : {0}", LogData(3))
    End If
    w.WriteLine("Application version: " & Application.ProductVersion)
    w.WriteLine("-------------------------------")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check length of array

```
Public Shared Sub Log2(LogData() As String, w As IO.TextWriter)
    w.Write(vbCrLf)
    w.WriteLine("Log Entry          : {0} - {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
    w.WriteLine("username : {0}", LogData(0))
    w.WriteLine("Action   : {0}", LogData(1))
    w.WriteLine("Domain   : {0}", LogData(2))

    If LogData.Length = 4 Then'<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        w.WriteLine("Address   : {0}", LogData(3))
    End If

    w.WriteLine("Application version: " & Application.ProductVersion)
    w.WriteLine("-------------------------------")
End Sub
```